# How to activate venv which is created by PyCharm via shell?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, python-venv

I want to activate Python Project, which created by PyCharm via shell.
It has *venv* directory, but it does not contain **bin/activate** script.
So how I can activate it?

```
Project-Dir
  |- some.py
  |- venv
       |-Include
       |-Lib
          |- ...
       |- Script
       |- pip-selfcheck.json
       |-pyenv.cfg
```

Environment:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6 anaconda\python.exe
- PyCharm 2018.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to activate your virtual env, go to you `Project-dir` using cmd.

From there type:

> venv\Scripts\activate.bat

Your virtual env python interpreter should be added at beginning of prompt, like this:

> (venv) C:\Users\my-name>

Run your `some.py` file using:

> (venv) C:\Users\my-name>python some.py

If you are using shell, for example *git-bash* or something else, use:

> source venv\Scripts\activate

For more info, please read [virtualenv userguide](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/)